# socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0) Fail return -1

Tags: android, c, sockets

In android M, I compiled a daemon and driver communication, which the program has to use

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;
char buffer[1024];
mcSocket_t *mcs = (mcSocket_t *)data;

/* initialize socket */
mcs->sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if(mcs->sock < 0)
{
   //LOGE("%s: error on socket(): %d", __func__, mcs->sock);
    LOGE("%s: error on socket(): %d = %s", __func__, errno, strerror(errno));
   goto exitCommandThread;
}
bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(mcs->port);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

/* bind to address and port */
if (0 != bind(mcs->sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)))
{
   LOGE("%s: error on bind(): %d = %s", __func__, errno, strerror(errno));
   running = 0;
}
```

But I executed  ***/system/bin/daemon*** ，socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); always returns mcs->sock=-1，print：error on socket(): 13 = Permission denied

Comment: What's the error that gets printed?  That will tell you *why* it failed.

Comment: The LOGE("%s: error on socket(): %d = %s", __func__, mcs->sock, strerror(errno));
--print：mCube_CommandThread: error on socket(): -1 = Permission denied

Comment: Probably you get `EACCESS`. Does user that launches /system/bin/daemon have internet access permission?

Comment: @Serhio: From just trying to create a socket, it is not clear to where it would connect to. It could very well be used to set up a local connection only.

Comment: How can I add  internet access permission？

Comment: @iking First of all you should check that `EACCESS == errno` is true after call to `socket()`.

Comment: @alk `socket(PF_INET)` makes no doubts in your intentions.

Comment: @Serhio  The func mcs->sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); print：mcs->sock  is -1

Comment: @iking Bad idea on the edit.  **Always** print the error code / message when a library / system function fails.

Comment: @iking Please provide extended info about fault - tell the value of `errno` after call to `socket()` (about errno: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)

Comment: @Serhio; You are right, I overlooked the 1st comment form *iking*. This definitely is an `EACCES`.

Comment: "*How can I add [...] access permission？*": http://android.stackexchange.com/q/38388

Comment: @all I update the LOGE(....), the print:error on socket(): 13 = Permission denied

Comment: @alk It depends on the way how binary is started. If it is just a binary inside regular apk file - you can add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to manifest. If it is started from `init.rc` at system startup - it should be OK, since it inherits root access.

Comment: I am not the Android guy, but I feel connecting to `127.0.0.1:12345` isn't connecting to the "*INTERNET*" ... but well ... :-/ @Serhio

Comment: @ Serhio the daemon is started from init.rc at system startup

Comment: the init.rc:
service daemon /system/bin/daemon
    disabled
    user system
    group system
    class main

Comment: @iking Then you need investigate daemon startup deeper and it is out of scope of this question.

Comment: @alk Forbidding of `socket(PF_INET)` is easier and less error-prone to implement than tracking of miscellaneous corner cases. So IMO it is an expected decision.

Comment: @Serhio I do not think it is a daemon startup problems, because the daemon failed to start due to socket failure caused

Comment: @iking Okay, lets track your UIDs.  Put `LOGE("uid: %d, euid: %d\n", getuid(), geteuid());`  at the `main()` begin and immediately before `socket()`.

Comment: @Serhio  the main ：uid: 1000, euid: 1000  before socket()：uid: 1000, euid: 1000